# How to get the content of a HTTPS post request on the server side?

Tags: php, apache, post, https

I have a C client which use libcurl to send xml packet to Apache server via HTTPS.

some parts of the client code as:

```
curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/test.php");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, send_buf);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, strlen(send_buf));
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

The content of send_buf is sent to https apache server (https://example.com/test.php), but on the Apache server side, how can I use test.php to get the content of send_buf? Any other scripts are welcome. thanks

Any example codes?

Comment: Not quite sure why you asked this again, would be nice if you didn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be a little unclear on your question, but I'm assuming send_buf is in the standard format, ie,

foo=bar&baz=boo&x=17+cats+etc

In that case, in your receiving PHP script (test.php) the $_POST variable will be initialized as follows:

```
$_POST['foo'] = "bar"
$_POST['baz'] = "boo"
$_POST['x'] = "17 cats etc"
```

So you can access a value by using $_POST['foo'].

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think i need to change the question to : How to get the send_buf content using cgi .c code. I 'd like to use a c code in apache /var/www/cgi-bin/ to get the POST request data. any example C codes for that?

Comment: It sounds like it's not really a PHP-related question. Here's some documentation on processing POST requests via CGI in C: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html#post -- basically the POST data goes to stdin of the program. Not too many people use "traditional" CGI in C anymore...

Answer (score 0):

To get everything that is sent (POST) to your Apache server via your test.php file, you can use:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

You could also use $_GET if you wanted to get everything passed in the URL (like: https://example.com/test.php?myvar=value).  Finally, $_REQUEST contains both $_POST and $_GET.

If you post a variable called `myvar`via your C code, you can retrieve the value in your test.php file with:

```
<?php
    print $_POST['myvar'];
?>
```